# Using strings with if statements

Tags: string, if-statement

I have this code:

```
public UILabel Error;

void OnRegister(GameObject g)
{
 if (Error.text.Equals("That e-mail address is in use. Use password recovery if you forgot your password."))
 {

    Error.text= "Inserisci un indirizzo di posta elettronica (email) valido. Questa operazione e’ importante per recuperare la tua parola chiave (password), nel momento in cui l’hai dimenticata.";
    return;
 }
}
```

What i wanted to do is when the string is entered to the UILabel, when a button(having the function OnRegister) it would translate the string to italian. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. You've posted some code and stated what you want to do. What is the problem you're asking us to help you with?

Comment: It's anti-pattern.. Use xml file to translate your strings.

Comment: What language and platform are you using?

Comment: I think it's c# with mono

Comment: im using c# with mono